# Asymmetric Encryption with node js and Decryption with Python

Tags: python, node.js, encryption

I have trouble with encryption and description using node js and python.

First create public/private keys,

```sh
openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 4096
openssl rsa -pubout -in private_key.pem -out public_key.pem
```

then in nodejs

```js
const crypto = require("crypto")
const fs = require("fs")
var encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./public_key.pem', 'utf8'), 
    padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING, 
    oaepHash: 'sha256'},
    Buffer.from("123456"))
encrypted = encrypted.toString('base64')
```

Now I try to decrypt `encrypted` in python

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding

with open("./private_key.pem", "rb") as key_file:
    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        key_file.read(),
        password=None,
        backend=default_backend()
    )

original_message = private_key.decrypt(
    encrypted,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        label=None
    )
)
```

the decryption method raises an error

```
ValueError: Ciphertext length must be equal to key size.
```

I think the problem is different padding but I do not know how to use proper paddings.
These are my sources
[Link1](https://boobo94.github.io/devops/tutorials/asymmetric-encryption-with-nodejs/)
[Link2](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/asymmetric-encryption-and-decryption-in-python/)

Comment: `encrypted` in the Python code must be Base64 decoded before decryption. If this is done, encryption and decryption work with the posted code, otherwise the posted exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks @Topaco. replacing `encrypted` with `base64.b64decode(encrypted)`  solve the problem.